# Ordered Permutations

Tags: r, permutation

I am looking to generate ordered permutation for large numbers i.e. 37P10 (permutations for 37 of size 10). I am using `combinat` package, `permn()` function for the purpose but it does not work for more than 10 numbers. Also through this i cannot be able to generate permutation of different sizes as describe above in example.

Further, I am combining these permutation into a matrix using `do.call(rbind,)` function.Is any any other package in R-language that may be used for the purpose please?

Comment: `37P10` is `1264020397516800` that's a **LOT** of permutation and that too ordered. I doubt you can do this in any trivial manner on any trivial desktop setup.

Comment: @geektrader this very much important for me please do help.

Comment: @geektrader I want to infer some important combination from these, if there is any method then i can do my work very easily and fast otherwise.....

Comment: Even if you iteratively compute each permutation, `rbind` will fail. BTW, what is the system RAM?

Comment: If it were possible, and I have understood you correctly you could use `combn()`. To get all combinations of the numbers 1:37, taken 10 at a time, you can use `combn(1:37,10)`. As @geektrader has already said, doubtful it's possible to generate all 1.26 quadrillion combinations on your desktop....

Comment: @SimonO101 actually i need ordered sets and use them one by one into a test.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  As the other comments point out, you can never evaluate all these combs/perms, so let's look at finding the ones you actually want.

Comment: @user2053413 If you aren't sure of the combs you want yet, a better explanation of what the intended output is may better help to arrive at a solution.

Comment: What you've asked for simply cannot be done. You're asking to generate and store 1.22e15 (or 4.81e15 with replacement) permutations of 10 numbers. Even if each number were only one byte, you would need **10 million** GB of RAM.  There's probably a way to solve your underlying problem, but we can't help unless you provide more details about what you're trying to do with all these permutations.

Comment: What's an ordered permutation?

Comment: ordered set of numbers i.e. `3P2=6` so there is 6 possible way to arrange number 1 to 3 in ordered sequence. **1.** 1,2,3 **2.** 2,1,3 **3.** 3,2,1 **4.** 3,1,2 **5.** 1,3,2 and **6.** 2,3,1. got it??

Comment: But shouldn't the elements of `3P2` be `{1,2}`, `{2,1}`, `{1,3}`, `{3,1}`, `{2,3}`, `{3,2}` ? (i.e. there are indeed six possible elements, but you have enumerated the full permutations, not the samples of 2 ... `3P2` = 3!/(3-2)! = 6 is the same as `3P3` = 3!/(3-3)! = 6 ...

Comment: @BenBolker     thanks for the correction. Actually at that time I was in sleepy mood.

Comment: @user2053413: nPm  doesn't give possible ways to arrange n elements. Number of ways n elements can be arranged is n factorial (n!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've asked for simply cannot be done. You're asking to generate and store 1.22e15 (or 4.81e15 with replacement) permutations of 10 numbers. Even if each number were only one byte, you would need **10 million GB** of RAM.

In my [LSPM](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/lspm) package, I use the function `LSPM:::.nPri` to generate a specific permutation based on its lexically ordered index.  There's no way you will be able to iterate over *every* permutation in an reasonable amount of time, so I would suggest that you take a sample of all possible permutations.

Note that the above code will not work for nPr(37,10) due to precision issues with such a large number, but it should work as a good starting point.

Comment: thank. Kindly advise me. Is it possible to write a function in R that returns only a (one) set of permutation at a time and then overwrite next set on it iteratively and so on...?

Answer (score 3):

It is near impossible to generate so many permutation on the normal computer.

Quick calculations shows `(37 P 10)` is `1264020397516800`. To store this many integers itself, you would need `1264020397516800 x 64` bits. That is `8.09×10^7 Gb  (gigabits)` or `10^7 Gigabytes`. Then to store actual permutation information you will need even more "memory"  either in RAM or Harddisk.

I think best strategy would be to write permutation function, creates ordered permutation sequentially, and do your analysis iteratively without generating all possible permutations.

Comment: thanks a lot for valuable answer and i fully understand what should i further do, Kindly can you help me out to make ordered permutation function?

Comment: it's not clear to me from the description so far that a random sample of permutations (the probability of getting two identical permutations is vanishingly small) wouldn't serve equally well for the purpose, and `sample()` is very straightforward.

Comment: @BenBolker I have used this function but after about an  hour it could not able to return the required set of numbers. Any one or more set(s) from all possible sets of order permutations may satisfy my required condition.

Comment: I still don't understand. `sample(37,10)` returns an ordered set of 10 values drawn without replacement from the numbers 1 to 37.  `replicate(1000,sample(37,10))` returns a 10-by-1000 matrix of 1000 such draws. Can you specify more precisely what you need?

Comment: @BenBolker. I have a check process to find neighbor values where order really matter. In this process, 10 different number are used as input at a time, if it satisfy the condition then the process will terminate otherwise repeat with a new set.